# Intercept all responses in Play 2.1

Tags: java, playframework, httpresponse, playframework-2.1

Is there a way to intercept all HTTP responses in using Play Framework 2.1?

This is what I have in my Global.java file to intercept all requests, but I'm also looking to intercept responses:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private static BasicAuthHandler AUTH;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {

        if ( ... ) {
            return new Action.Simple() {

                @Override
                public Result call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
                    return unauthorized();
                }
            };
        }

        return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    }
}
```

I've read the documentation on [manipulating the response](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaResponse) but it only describes how to do it for each result individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TransactionalAction](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/java/play/db/jpa/TransactionalAction.html) is an example of request/response interceptor. It extends [Action](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/java/play/mvc/Action.html) and provides [Transactional](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/java/play/db/jpa/Transactional.html) annotation which targets controller type or method.

Example of controller method annotated with action:

```
@Transactional
public static Result ok(){
    return ok();
}
```

[More details](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaActionsComposition).

An example of action logging responses (mind, actions which do not provide annotations like [Transactional](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/java/play/db/jpa/Transactional.html), extend Action.Simple):

```
public class LogAction extends Action.Simple {

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        F.Promise<Result> call = delegate.call(ctx);
        return call.map(r -> {
            String responseBody = new String(JavaResultExtractor.getBody(r, 0L));
            Logger.info(responseBody);
            return r;
        });
    }
}
```

Usage, method definition:

```
@With(LogAction.class)
public static Result ok(){
    return ok();
}
```

Usage, class definition - all  methods intercepted:

```
@With(LogAction.class)
public class BaseController extends Controller {

    ....

}
```

You can go one step forward, if you dont like @With annotation. Define custom annotation yourself:

```
@With({ LogAction.class })
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {
}
```

and use it this way:

```
@Log
public static Result ok(){
    return ok();
}
```

If your custom annotation accepts parameters, change LogAction definition this way:

```
public class LogAction extends Action<Log> {
    // use configuration object to access your custom annotation configuration
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that I have to add the `@With()` annotation above all of the controller methods that return results?

Comment: You can put it at class or method definition level.